# Chrome - Old password keeps auto filling instead of new saved one

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac, passwords, keychain

I'm going crazy with this problem. When I go to Paypal's sign in page, the saved password is the old one, despite the fact that I have the proper password showing as saved everywhere.

I can't tell if it's Keychain (shows nothing saved for Paypal though), or Chrome passwords (which absolutely shows the correct new one under Manage Passwords), or Last Pass which also ONLY shows the new password.

I cannot figure out where this old one is coming from or why it keeps auto filling when there is no instance of that password anywhere.

It's not a huge deal, I just hit auto fill but I log in and out of Paypal a lot during my day and it should just be filled correctly.

I'm on a 2012 Macbook Pro using Chrome (it doesn't happen in Safari).

Comment: check for other instances in Chrome Managed Passwords for paypal.com with a leading space.

Comment: Potentially, old password is stored in your login keychain, new is in the iCloud keychain. Safari knows this, Chrome doesn't. Search for dupes; newest will be the good one - or make sure you know the password, delete all matches, start over.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have searched for anything related to Paypal but nothing else comes up at all. There's no duplicates. I have deleted and started over and it worked for a few days but that same old/mysterious password keeps auto filling.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for me, in a LastPass record. I just discovered that if you edit a password, then hit another edit button inside the edit window, you get all the key value pairs that the site has used in the past. In there, **I saw old versions of my password** and removed them.

Edit button inside the edit panel:
[image]

Second edit screen (fields obfuscated):
[image]

Before this, I had the same problem and scoured every autofill source I could think of. I even removed anything old and unidentifiable... all to no avail.